# How to call method of Customer from Catalogue not from Library

Tags: java, class, methods

I have 3 classes named Library, Customer and Catalogue. I am doing this code on Netbeans.

**This is my Library Class**

```
public class Library {

    private Catalogue catalogue;
    private List<Customer> customers;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Library library = new Library();
    }

    public Library() {
        catalogue = new Catalogue(this);
        customers = new LinkedList<Customer>();
    }
}
```

**This is my Catalogue class**

```
public class Catalogue {

    private Library library;

    public Catalogue(Library library) {
        this.library = library;
    }
}
```

**This is my Customer Class**

```
public class Customer {

    private int ID;
    private String name;
    private int balance;

    public Customer(int ID, String name, int balance) {
        this.ID = ID;
        this.name = name;
        this.balance = balance;
    }
}
```

As seen above sample code, I can directly call customer from Library, but my question is that how can I also call customer from Catalogue. **The restrictions are I cannot add fields of Customer in Catalogue and also I cannot add any field of Customer in Library too.**

Based on the above example I have to call customer from catalogue.

Thanks

Comment: You cannot call methods of a class without any object of that class unless those methods are static.

Comment: I am really not sure what you want to do but have you thought about just adding a `List<Customer> getCustomers()` getter?

Comment: What method of `Customer` would you like to call from `Catalogue`?

Comment: @AshwinKKumar Thanks for your reple mate. I have to stick around the specification provided from my work I cannot use static. If I have to use a customer methods on library then I will create a for each loop and with the variable created on for each loop i can call all the methods of Customer class. So same thing I want to do on Catalogue class. Thanks

Comment: @Ben Thanks for your reply mate. Same getter and setter I can use directly in the library by creating a for each loop of a customer and with that variable, I can extract all the possible methods of Customer in Library class. But due to restrictions; I cannot create any objects of Customer in catalogue. But I can call library from Catalogue . But my problem is that how can I call customer from Catalogue using library. Thanks.

Comment: @KevinAnderson Thanks for your reply mate. I wanna call every possible methods of customer from Catalogue. I ca call directly from Library but I need same from Catalogue. But from Catalogue I can call Library class and how can I call Customer from Library using library.

Comment: Then write the `getCustomers()` getter and use `this.library.getCustomers()` as suggested by Ben. Or a method in library to get a `LinkedList<Customer>::iterator`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to go through Library. Add a method in Library that calls Customer and use that in Catalogue.

Comment: Can you please provide that code please if you don't mind.

Comment: You didn't provide any method for Customer that can be called or any hint how to identify the customer you want to call or if to call all. To write actual code you need to flesh out your question a lot more.

Comment: Sorry mate if I wanna call getCustomerID() from catalogue how can I call?

Comment: `this.library.getCustomerID()` Whatever code you want to write in Catalogue write it in Librfary instead and then simply call it.

Comment: Thanks Mate, I got it. if I have a method name public String rentBook() in my library then what is the string value do I have to return so that in the catalogue I can call the the rentBook() from catalogue.